# Azure - difference in publish website and deploy on Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

What is the difference between publishing a website on azure and deploying it on an azure virtual machine?

Answer (score -2):

Azure offers several ways to host web sites: **Azure App Service**, **Virtual Machines**, **Service Fabric**, and **Cloud Services**.

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm) helps you understand the options and make the right choice for your web application.